# New to Emacs, Emacs seems not interpret my keys properly?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm an avid Vim user. My Vimrc counts more than 800 lines. I'm a tinkerer who loves to customize every single part of my environment. Emacs seems to be more easy to configure. So I'm giving Emacs a try.

When you want to zoom out, you press in Emacs C-x C-+

It works fine. But I would like to remap the zoom out, without the need to press C-x. So just pressing C-+.. 
I checked the command name for zooming, with

```
C-h (help) k (key) C-x C-+ (the key binding)
```

Then I get the function text-scale-adjust, with the - as parameter.

In my .emacs file, I mapped this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-+") 'text-scale-adjust +)
```

When I load the init file again in Emacs, the C-+ will not work. I get the message in Emacs when start it up again:

"Symbol's name as variable is void: +"

What did I wrong?

Comment: just get rid of the `+` after `text-scale-adjust`

Comment: 800 lines, that's cute by Emacs standards :). Consider using `text-scale-increase` and `text-scale-decrease`.

Comment: Whehehe, even 800 lines is cute? I'm curious then. When I get the command when I catch the key with C-h k, I see only text-scale-adjust +.
How know you that you need the command text-scale-increase? 

Could you tell that? Then I'm more able to sorting my issues out before I ask anything here. :)

Comment: You can use `M-x apropos` or `M-x apropos-command` and then give it a list of keywords or a regular expression.  So, for example `M-x apropos-command` then `text scale` at the prompt gives you some suggestions to consider.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. When I'm typing M-x apropos-text-scale-adjust, I will only see the text-scale-adjust and the key combinations, with the expaination. But I stil don't see text-scale increase/decrease. What would it best to me to get know such things?

Comment: Try using space separated keywords rather than the full symbol.  Example: `M-x apropos` then, when it prompts you, enter `text scale` (notice no dash between `text` and `scale`).

Comment: For example, I would like to remap the keys for saving, So C-s make it save. I get the command saving-buffer back when I see in the help for the keys C-x C-s. Remapping it to saving-buffer doesn't  work. When I do M-x apropos-save-buffer, he says the command doesn't exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome!  I presume you're using `evil` to get Vim modal editing?

Either of the two suggestions so far (get rid of the `+`, or use `text-scale-increase`) will work for the specific use case.  So, either `(global-set-key (kbd "C-+") 'text-scale-adjust)` or `(global-set-key (kbd "C-+") 'text-scale-increase)` will work.

More generally, if you want to pass an argument to the function, you could wrap it in a `lambda` like so:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-+") (lambda ()
                              (interactive)
                              (text-scale-increase 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your tip about lambda is interesting, but I found your another tip about M-x apropos more useful. :). And yes, I'm currently using Evil now. Now trying to change everything in Emacs in Vim-like way, and then expand Emacs, while Vim isn't able to do that. :)